TV programme or movie where people die in an elevator
OK so this is something I watched on television about 7 years ago, I really want to say it's a movie but this is all I remember:
Its a crime investigation of a suspected murder of people in a hotel lift, in which it falls from the top story of a hotel with many people in including a little girl
At some point we find that an old lady that is being interviewed in her home is the twin sister of the girl that dies
I also remember that this old woman (the surviving twin) is the one who killed them out of jealousy 
Thank you in advance :)

Sounds like Tower of Terror from 1997 with Steve Guttenberg and Kirsten Dunst. From the recap: 

The film begins in Halloween 1939, revolving around the fate of five people - singer Carolyn Crosson, her boyfriend Gilbert London, child actress Sally Shine (who is modeled after child actress Shirley Temple), her nanny Emeline Partridge, and bellhop Dewey Todd... lightning strikes the building which causes the elevator to collapse, and the five people mysteriously vanish... The scene then travels to almost sixty years later... The team [investigating this] realize that [old woman] Abigail was the one responsible for the disappearance of the hotel guests on the elevator, including her younger sister Sally... out of personal vendetta and jealousy against her sister's booming career.

The trailer, as well as the movie itself, are available on Youtube.
